# Adding multiple users to Assigned To Column

Tags: 2010

How do I add multiple users to the 'Assigned To' column. I changed the List Settings for this column to 'Allow Multiple Selections' still it shows an error 'You are only allowed to enter one item' when I try to add more than one name.